# JS closures with deep nesting

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

There is the following code of NPM module:

```
var actions = {};
var methods = ['POST', 'GET', 'PATCH', 'DELETE'];

methods.forEach(function(method) {
  actions['mock' + method] = function(browser, url, response) {
    browser.execute(function() {
      result[method][url] = response;
    });
  }
});

module.exports = actions;
```

I want to have 4 methods: mockPOST, mockGET, mockDELETE, mockPATCH. Each method should just execute `browser.execute` with callback function and put `response` in the appropriate `result` field - `result['POST']` in the `mockPOST` and so on. But when I execute

```
utils.mockPOST(browser, 'auth', {"result": "OK"});
```

I get `method is not defined` error. What should I do? Thanks!

Comment: `result` is not defined.

Comment: result is not the reason, but browser.execute is may be. How can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see you are using selenium or webdriver for node.js. That makes things a littlebit tricky. You cannot use closures in the `browser.execute` function, and the reason is it does not run there at all. Webdriver will convert the function to a string, will transfer it to the browser, and will `eval` that string inside the browser. The nodejs closure is not transferred to the browser, only the function code as a string.

I assume the `result` object is defined globally inside the browser already.

So what can you do about it? I always recommend not to put function literals inside `browser.execute` and `browser.executeAsync` as they are confusing. You can put there a string instead, which will be evaluated. Try the following:

```
methods.forEach(function(method) {
  actions['mock' + method] = function(browser, url, response) {
    var browserAction = "result[" + JSON.stringify(method) + "]" +
        "[" + JSON.stringify(url) + "] = " +
        JSON.stringify(response) + ";";
    browser.execute(browserAction);
  };
});
```